# Preserve variable's value for $http.get async result processing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

Let us consider that we have a function, invoked on some event (let's say - `scroll` event). This function loads more items into some list.

Suppose that the logic of this function is designed as follows:

```
function() {
    oldSize = list.length;

    // add new items (prepare them in advance)
    for (i = 0; i < PAGE_SIZE; i++) list.push({});

    $http.get("/next/page/" + oldSize).then(function() {
       // here I want operate with oldSize value which is actual on moment of 
       // the $http.get invocation:
       for (i = 0; i < PAGE_SIZE;i++) {
          // do something with 
          list[oldSize + i] = ... ;
       }
     }
}
```

The problem is that the entire function can be invoked almost simultaneously multiple times, what leads to the effect, that `.then(function() {` operates with improper value of `oldSize` variable - it becomes the value of last `list.length`, while I need it be preserved as it was on the moment of invocation.

For instance, if this event listener was invoked almost simultaneously 2 times, it will be:

1. `oldSize == 5`, list increased by 10 (for example) elements. But inside `$http.get(...).then()` I need to work with value `oldSize == 5`.
2. Second invocation: `oldSize == 15` (because we have increased list by 10 elements in the first invocation). So inside **this** particular `$http.get(...).then()` I want to have `oldSize == 15`.

I hope it is clear. Please, do not suggest me to change my logic. I just want to know how to save variable value for postponed result of the asynchronous function (in my case it is `$http.get(...).then(...)`). Thanks.

Comment: Why do you define `oldSize` in outer scope?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko where should I define it if I need to save its value before the invocation of get method?

Comment: If you don't use it outside this function (and nested callbacks) you could simply do `var oldSize = list.length`. Otherwise check my answer below.

Comment: So, the problem is only in an absent of the `var ` keyword?

Comment: Yes. Using undefined variables w/o "use strict" pragma makes them defined in global scope (check `window.oldSize`)

Comment: Okay, thank you @YuryTarabanko, this solves my problem. I hope you are not a downvoter, because I am going to accept your answer :-)

Comment: :) I didn't downvote. I thought you might be using `oldSize` somewhere outside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are not able to define `oldSize` inside this function because you need it somewhere else.

```
function() {
    oldSize = list.length;

    // add new items (prepare them in advance)
    for (i = 0; i < PAGE_SIZE; i++) list.push({});


    var currentOldSize = oldSize;

    $http.get("/next/page/" + oldSize).then(function() {
       // here I want operate with oldSize value which is actual on moment of 
       // the $http.get invocation:
       for (i = 0; i < PAGE_SIZE;i++) {
          // do something with 
          list[currentOldSize + i] = ... ;
       }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why is `oldSize` declared outside the scope or globally? Declare the variable in the scope of the function.

```
let list = [];

function() {
    let size = list.length;

    $http.get(...)
        .then(function() {
            // handle size
            [...]
        });
};
```